# The following code is not displaying toast message for the first time

Tags: android

**Here is the code**

```
package com.Wase.edittext;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.Wase.edittext.R;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

 private EditText edittext;
 private EditText edittext1;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_android_app);

    addKeyListener();
 edittext.requestFocus();
}



 public void addKeyListener() {

    // get edittext component
    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);



    // add a keylistener to keep track user input
    edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        // if keydown and "enter" is pressed
            if(keyCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO)
        {
            edittext1.requestFocus();
            return true;
        }

        edittext1.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onEditorAction(TextView a, int b, KeyEvent c) {

        // if keydown and "enter" is pressed
             if(b == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {

            //hide the keyboard
             InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
             imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
             imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext1.getWindowToken(), 0);
        // display a floating message
            Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this, edittext.getText().toString() + " " + edittext1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
} });
        return false;
}
    });
 }
}
```

This code will not display toast message first time. user has to go back to the first edit text. retype the text . comeback to second edit text and retype and then has to click on go to display the toast.

Please help to resolve

Comment: why do you have edittext1 `OnEditorActionListener` inside of editext one

Comment: if you use  edittext.requestFocus(); to open toast u can try edittext.performClick(); maybe this works.

Comment: Can you point the line number

Comment: It wont help because i need to display after clicking on Go virtual keyboard button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public void addKeyListener() {

    // get edittext component
    edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);



    // add a keylistener to keep track user input
    edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {



        // if keydown and "enter" is pressed
        if (keyCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {

          edittext1.requestFocus();
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
    edittext1.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onEditorAction(TextView a, int b, KeyEvent c) {


        // if keydown and "enter" is pressed
        if (b == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {

          // hide the keyboard
          InputMethodManager imm =
              (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
          imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
          imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext1.getWindowToken(), 0);


          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
              edittext.getText().toString() + " " + edittext1.getText().toString(),
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


          return true;
        } else {

          return false;
        }
      }
    });


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
public void addKeyListener() {

        // get edittext component
        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);



        // add a keylistener to keep track user input
        edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            // if keydown and "enter" is pressed
                if(keyCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO)
            {
                edittext1.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }


            return false;
         } });

         edittext1.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                 @Override
                 public boolean onEditorAction(TextView a, int b, KeyEvent c) {

            // if keydown and "enter" is pressed
                 if(b == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {

                //hide the keyboard
                 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
                 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext1.getWindowToken(), 0);
            // display a floating message
                Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this, edittext.getText().toString() + " " + edittext1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
          } });

     }
```

your edittext.setOnEditorActionListener method's parentheses -- } --  is closed wrong line.

Comment: If i try this the value in the object edittext will be there till the toast is ended

Comment: It doesn't matter for private type.
The problem is ,i understood, you define OnEditorActionListener for edittext1 inside the edittext setOnEditorActionListener.